# What is shards in kinesis data stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, data-stream

What is shards in kinesis data stream and partition key. I read aws documents but I don't get it. Can someone explain it in simple terms?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [Amazon Kinesis Data Streams Terminology and Concepts - Amazon Kinesis Data Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/key-concepts.html):

> A **shard** is a uniquely identified sequence of data records in a stream. A stream is composed of one or more shards, each of which provides a fixed unit of capacity. Each shard can support up to 5 transactions per second for reads, up to a maximum total data read rate of 2 MB per second and up to 1,000 records per second for writes, up to a maximum total data write rate of 1 MB per second (including partition keys). The data capacity of your stream is a function of the number of shards that you specify for the stream. The total capacity of the stream is the sum of the capacities of its shards.

So, a shard has two purposes:

- A certain amount of capacity/throughput
- An ordered list of messages

If your application must **process *all* messages in order**, then you can only use one shard. Think of it as a line at a bank — if there is one line, then everybody gets served in order.

However, if messages only need to be **ordered for a certain *subset* of messages**, they can be sent to separate shards. For example, multiple lines in a bank, where each line gets served in order. Or, think of a bus sending GPS coordinates. Each bus sends messages to only a single shard. A shard might contain messages from multiple buses, but each bus only sends to *one* shard. This way, when the messages from that shard is processed, all messages from a particular bus are processed in order.

This is controlled by using a **Partition Key**, which identifies the source. The partition key is hashed and assigned to a shard. Thus, all messages with the same partition key will go to the same shard.

At the back-end, there is a **typically one worker per shard** that is processing the messages, in order, from that shard.

If your system **does not care about preserving message order**, then use a **random partition key**. This means the message will be sent to any shard.

Comment: So shards contains a set of data records. Maximum size of data record can be 1mb and shards can have max 1000 records. So does that mean max size of a shards is 1000mb??

Comment: Shards do not quite "contain" records. Think of them as a hose, through which records pass. The hose can only accept a certain quantity of messages (water) over a period of time. If you want to send more water, you need more hoses in parallel (more shards in parallel).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Do you know what they exactly mean by a `transaction` in `5 transactions per second for reads`. They didn't explicitly mention what they mean by a transaction in the docs

Comment: Found it. `GetRecords` is a a read transaction which can get 10k records, and they allow 5 of these read transactions per second https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetRecords.html

Comment: @JohnRotenstein do you mean *sub**s**et* of messages?

Comment: @Peer Oopsie! Fixed.