# Boto3 get_records: Missing required parameter in input: "ShardId"

Tags: amazon-web-services, sharding, amazon-kinesis

I am using Boto3 with Kinesis. I want Kinesis to return a single item from the stream.

This is my code:

```py
kinesis = boto3.client('kinesis')
iterator = kinesis.get_shard_iterator(
     StreamName = "requests",
     ShardIteratorType='LATEST'
)

response = kinesis.get_records(
     ShardIterator = iterator,
     Limit = 1,
     StreamName = "requests",
)

print(response)
```

It fails with this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "ShardId"
```

on the line where I initialize the iterator, so I know I'm missing a parameter, but what do I set `ShardId` to? If the answer varies from stream to stream, what exactly is a `ShardId`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The core problem is that [`get_shard_iterator`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html?highlight=kinesis#Kinesis.Client.get_shard_iterator) requires a `ShardId` argument passed to it.**

---

The shard ID is the unique identifier of a shard within a stream.

To obtain the `ShardId` (or `ShardId`s to then pick from) for your stream, first call  [`describe_stream`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html?highlight=kinesis#Kinesis.Client.describe_stream).

```py
stream = client.describe_stream(StreamName='requests')
```

This will return to you a response object with a list of stream objects with a JsonPath of `response.StreamDescription.Shards`.

Each object in this array will have a `ShardId`. Dependent on how you've configured your Kinesis stream, you will have 1 or more shard objects in this array.

If you have 1 shard, the below should allow you to pick the first shard ID & proceed with the rest of your code:

```py
kinesis = boto3.client('kinesis')

stream = client.describe_stream(StreamName='requests')
shard_id = stream['StreamDescription']['Shards'][0]['ShardId']

iterator = kinesis.get_shard_iterator(
     StreamName = "requests",
     ShardIteratorType='LATEST',
     ShardId = shard_id
)

response = kinesis.get_records(
     ShardIterator = iterator,
     Limit = 1
)

print(response)
```

---

To learn more about shards themselves (out of scope), start by reading this great [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56520703/4800344) by [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein).